# Android : Hide corners of custom progressbar

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I am trying to design a custom progressbar but not able to hide its corners.  I am trying to highlight the white patches near the corners, highlighted by black circles.

[image]

I tried the following code, but it is not working

```
customProgressbar.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
```

here is my drawable file

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<solid android:color="@color/pale_orange" />
<stroke android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="10dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="10dp"
    android:topRightRadius="10dp" />

<padding
    android:bottom="3dp"
    android:left="3dp"
    android:right="3dp"
    android:top="3dp" />
</shape>
```

Here is my XML layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@drawable/progressbar_background"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Loading.."
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help in getting a solution. Many thanks!

Comment: post the xml layout where you used the custom shape

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin please see edited question. I have updated XML layout file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**problem:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

As you could see the background color of your parent `RelativeLayout` is white thus giving you white background as you could from your sample image above.

**solution:**

set the background color of `RelativeLayout` to transparent to remove the white background

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: Yup! Upvoted, And accepting the ans. Can't accept ans withing 5 mins. :/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should replace this line in your relative layout

```
android:background="@color/white"
for
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```